# Python: Combine Lists

Tags: python, python-2.7

Maybe I'm overthinking it but I can't think of a way to combine lists in the way I need

```
[1,2,3,4,5]
['A','E','I','I','U']
```

To result in

```
[[1,'A'],[2,'E'],[3,'I'],[4,'O'],[5,'U']]
```

If I combine them, I get tuples/rounded brackets

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip).

If you want inner lists instead of inner tuples, maybe also use [`map`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map).

```
map(list, zip(list_1, list_2))
```

That will apply the `list` function to each tuple in the zipped up list, giving you a list of lists.

(The question specifies Python 2.7, but in Python 3, `map` does not return a list, so you would also have to apply the `list` function to the result of the map; i.e. `list(map(...))` )

Comment: I think this is more Pythonic than my answer.

Comment: @leovp No, I think list comprehensions are generally considered a very Pythonic way to do things.

Answer (score 3):

If you really need a list of lists, you'll have to do the following:

```
>>> a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
>>> b = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
>>> result = [list(zipped) for zipped in zip(a, b)]
>>> result
[[1, 'a'], [2, 'b'], [3, 'c'], [4, 'd'], [5, 'e']]
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) is for

```
list_a = [1,2,3,4,5]
list_b = ['A','E','I','I','U']

list_res = zip(list_a, list_b)        # Python 2.7
list_res = list(zip(list_a, list_b))  # Python 3 onward
```

If you indeed want the inner containers to be tuples, then you can use `map` as @khelwood proposed or a list-comprehension, or an explicit loop, or...

```
list_of_lists = map(list, list_res)        # Python 2.7
list_of_lists = list(map(list, list_res))  # Python 3 onward
```

Note the similar behavior of `map` and `zip` on the two Python versions. On python 2 they returned lists whereas on Python 3 they return iterators.

Comment: But you get tuples, which OP doesn't want.